# How to get parent param in Angular 8 Router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Need to access parent param from child.

/workspace/:workspaceId/:id

Need workspaceId in child component. In Angular 8 how we get parent param.

```
this.activateRoutes.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
 console.log(params.get('workspaceId'))
})
```

Comment: Can you show me your route configuration ?

Comment: you can just go with this.activateRoutes.parent.paramMap...